# How to setup maven for lsp-java

Tags: flycheck, lsp-mode, lsp, java

I need to import gurobi.jar to my project to correctly view the flycheck's errors.

I have read [Maven in 5 Minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) and [How to add local jar files to a Maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project) but I am still not able to correctly setup maven to fix flycheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of maven.
It is enough to put jars in a `lib` folder of the same project.

It could be necessary to clean (or manage):

- `~/.emacs.d/workspace`
- `~/.emacs.d/.lsp-session-v1`

Maybe useful: `M-x lsp`